# How to pass global to Plugin in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have a global object in my main controllers that I need to pass to a plugin controller, how do I achieve this and resolve the scope?

Comment: Why don't you just keep your plugin controllers, models, and views in the main app folder? Surely if a main controller _needs_ to pass the plugin a value, then it ceases to be a standalone plugin. You may want to create local app component(s) instead?

Comment: My plugin needs to hook into the methods of another object so it can manipulate any of its properties. A standalone plugin would not be able to do this. But I need the functionality of adding models on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you speaking about global object placed in app_controller.php of your application, then it's very easy, because all plugins extend AppController class. Basically what would be your code:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
   function beforeFilter(){
      $this->global_object = ... //the global object instance.
   }
}
```

Then because your plugin's AppControler extends applications's AppController you can access it in all plugin's controllers functions. For example:

```
class YourPluginAppController extends AppController {
    function doSomethingWithGlobalObject(){
        $this->global_object->doSome();//
    }
}
```

Hope this is what you asked.

Comment: That's great thanks. Basically my plugin needs to hook into the methods of another object so it can manipulate any of its properties. A standalone plugin would not be able to do this.